# swig: correct way to typemap a C++ buffer pointer in a result object back to java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

Foo.h that I want to swig:

```
#include <cstdint>

class Result
{
public:
    Result(const uint8_t *resultBuffer, int width, int height);

    const uint8_t *result;
    int width = -1;
    int height = -1;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Result doThing();

private:
    Context ctx;
};
```

Under the hood, Foo.doThing() does this:

```
// Context.buffer, a uint8_t*, points at allocated memory.
// that memory gets automatically freed when the Foo instance goes away.
//
// some stuff is written to ctx.buffer.
// int variables "bufferWidth" and "bufferHeight" are updated.
// multiplying them together gives size of ctx.buffer.
//
// finally:
Result result(ctx.buffer, ctx.bufferWidth, ctx.bufferHeight);
return result;
```

I want the result buffer to be a ByteBuffer on the Java side.  After some googling I came up with this swig interface file:

```
%module FooSwigModule

%include "stdint.i"

// FIXME:  likely wrong
%include "various.i"
%apply unsigned char *NIOBUFFER { uint8_t *resultBuffer };

%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "Foo.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "Foo.h"
```

Java side:

```
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Result result = foo.doThing();
    int width = result.get_width(); // OK
    int height = result.get_width(); // OK
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = result.get_result(); // SIGSEGV here
    // do things with result.get_result(), width, and height
    // ...
}
```

What should replace the two lines below FIXME in the swig interface file?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We're facing more or less the same issue....